# How to display a pop up window in Angular JS based on a Spring Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring

What is the best approach to display a pop up window or modal window in AngularJS based on the response from a Spring Controller. The pop up window should be able to carry the message from the controller and display it in the pop up window.

please let me know for suggestion

Comment: Is there any response status code return from the Spring Controller?

Comment: I would suggest ui.boostrap modal from angular. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/